# Membership always return false

Tags: c#, membership

my membership in c# app always returns false
I read all similar question in stack overflow
I changed AppName , passType .....
 but I could not solve it :( 
 , thanks for any help , 
my c# code is :

```
private void BtnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
           bool i = Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPass.Text);

            if (i)
            {
                    ClsVariable.UserId=new Guid(Membership.GetUser(txtUserName.Text).ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                    InsertLogin(ClsVariable.UserId.ToString());
                    MainForm fr = new MainForm();
                    fr.Show();
                    Hide();
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("username or password is not valid.");
            }
    }
```

my app.config is :

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Accountingf.Properties.Settings.DbAccountingConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=SHIMA-PC;Initial Catalog=DbAccounting;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Accountingf.Properties.Settings.DbAccountingConnectionString1"
      connectionString="Data Source=SHIMA-PC;Initial Catalog=DbAccounting;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership >
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
             type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="Accountingf.Properties.Settings.DbAccountingConnectionString"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
             requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             minRequiredPasswordLength="4"
             minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
             passwordStrengthRegularExpression="(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])"
             passwordFormat="Clear"
             applicationName="Accountingf"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I changed my c# code and it works  so my pass and username are correct!

```
 if(txtUserName.Text=="admin" && txtPass.Text=="1111")
    {
       MainForm fr = new MainForm();
       fr.Show();
```

Comment: Do you have users in your db set? There's not much one can guess just from seeing the code.

Comment: does the specified user exist, and is the password correct?

Comment: yes I have user in my db , I'm sure my u and p is correct :/

Comment: the `passwordFormat="Clear"` means the password is in cleartext, right? So you should easily be able to confirm that the username and password are correct by doing an SQL query.

Comment: I changed my c# code to : if(txtUserName.Text=="admin" && txtPass.Text=="1111")  and It works  so this shows my username and password are correct . sorry for my bad English

Comment: that only shows that the username and password are what *you think* they should be. it doesn't prove they are those values in the database.

Comment: you're right. in my database password is "2222" but when I try "1111" it works ! 
I don't know what should doing :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to check the state of the user directly on the Database

```
select * from aspnet_Membership
inner join aspnet_Users on aspnet_users.UserId = aspnet_Membership.UserId 
where aspnet_Users.UserName = 'admin'
```

for example you user could be locked out.

You can also make use of a all available helper stored procedures to make sure you have the right password. 
My advice is to first make sure that the user works fine on the db level and then try to find whatever might be wrong on code level.

Comment: Thanks , I try this query and shows my user Locked out 
I changed the field "IsLockedOut" to False but also didn't work

Comment: thanks very much :) 
in "aspnet_membership" table I changed  "IsLockedOut" field to "False" and changed "FailedPasswordAttemptCount" to "1"
and in app.config I changed applicationName to "applicationName="/" "
and it works now :)